# CodeIgniter Session spammed by bots

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2, bots

I have a site with roughly 2000 visitors per day, and the site is spammed with the various search engine bots. I tried reducing the session expire time to 20 minutes, and still I get alot of mysql_slow_queries. So I was looking into the article, [Google crawler, cron and codeigniter sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015585/google-crawler-cron-and-codeigniter-sessions), to fully ignore the bots **from the sessions table**, but the the way they do is, ignore the `IPs`, but as I was analyzing the database I see that the same bot uses different `IPs`. I noticed that the bots use the same user agent everytime though, so is it safe to ignore the user agents instead? What could be some of the necessary steps to avoid slow queries and ignore the bots?

Some of the SLOW Queries

```
INSERT INTO `ci_sessions` (`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `last_activity`, `user_data`) VALUES ('619bfd8ef4171480645feb17a15323ee', '219.92.135.144', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Firefox/3.6.15', 1384875135, '')

INSERT INTO `ci_sessions` (`session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `last_activity`, `user_data`) VALUES ('fa48b5168b8e84d90dc9b87ce65dfc89', '66.249.74.112', 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)', 1384875522, '')
```

Comment: Is this bot ignoring your robots.txt? YOu should block it at the firewall level, then, to keep it from sucking up any cpu resources, even if it'll still be clogging bandwidth.

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned, I just want to ignore it from the sessions table, not from crawling the site.

Comment: I'm kinda curious why with only 2k users a day, you have slow inserts? I have a high volume site (<10k) and run just fine off a linode VM.

Comment: I am not sure as well. It's usually at a certain timeframe, usually in the morning time (US timezone), that is when whole lot of bots crawls through the site. And I usually see overhead for the `ci_session` and I had to optimize that table everyday. I've indexed them as well. Not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit your `user_agent.php` in `/config`, and add the bots you see in your session, adding them to the bot section should eliminate the sessions from logging.

```
// There are hundreds of bots but these are the most common.
$robots = array(
    'googlebot'     => 'Googlebot',
    'msnbot'        => 'MSNBot',
    'baiduspider'   => 'Baiduspider',
    'bingbot'       => 'Bing',
    'slurp'         => 'Inktomi Slurp',
    'yahoo'         => 'Yahoo',
    'askjeeves'     => 'AskJeeves',
    'fastcrawler'   => 'FastCrawler',
    'infoseek'      => 'InfoSeek Robot 1.0',
    'lycos'         => 'Lycos',
    'yandex'        => 'YandexBot'
);
```

You can reduce the # of bots, but won't eliminate them. This user-agent process could be used to create a `MY_session.php` and then exclude session creation for agents matching bots.

**EDIT:**
I went ahead and created this on github and documented here:
http://blog.biernacki.ca/2014/01/codeigniter-keeping-bots-out-of-your-sessions-table-or-how-i-cleaned-up-my-sessions/

Enjoy

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how the session ignores the bots because I don't see anything about the session ignoring inside the core session class. Or were you telling me to extend the class and ignore it if its a robot?

Comment: Well I went ahead and created the drop in for you, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much =) Appreciate the extra steps you took to help me out =)

Comment: Great response! One wish: please rename My_Session.php to MY_Session.php in your git library. Otherwise it doesn't work with lowercase - looks like CI simply doesn't load the file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to block the bots completely, maybe try using `robots.txt`? If you only want to ignore the sessions being created, then checking user-agent for strings like "GoogleBot" may be a good solution. But you would need to extend the `Session` class to do that, I think.

Comment: Sorry I mean, block it off the Sessions table. Yeah, so you think it's better idea for blocking the user agent over ips?

Comment: It's a hard question - GoogleBot changes IP, but haven't changed the "GoogleBot" string in the user-agent for a long time now :) so it seems like checking user-agents is more reliable